# SwiftUI View not updating after @ObservedObject is changed

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, state, observedobject

**Intended Feature:**

1. Tap to add circle
2. Press "next" to create new "frame"
3. Drag circle to new position
4. Press "back" to revert circle to previous position

[image]

**Issue:**
As shown above, at the last part when I tap "back", the circle stays at dragged position instead of being reverted as intended.

e.g. When I add a circle to (0,0), create a new frame, drag the circle to a new location (10, 10) and tap "Back", the console prints "*Frame: 0, position (0,0)*". And when I tap next, it prints "*Frame: 1, position (10,10)*". And tapping "Back" prints (0,0) again. But the Circle position does not update.

I have tried using a class for the `DraggableCircleModel` struct and used @Published on its position but that didn't seem to work as well.

I provided my classes below to give some more context. Also this is only my second time posting a question here so any advice to improve my question would be appreciated. Thanks a bunch!

**Back and Next buttons**

```
Button(action: {
    self.viewModel.goTo(arrangementIndex: self.viewModel.currentIndex - 1)
}) { Text("Back") }

Button(action: {
    self.viewModel.goTo(arrangementIndex: self.viewModel.currentIndex + 1)
}) { Text("Next")}
```

**View used to present the circles:**

```
struct DisplayView: View {

@ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel

var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        Rectangle()
            .overlay(
                TappableView { location in
                    self.viewModel.addCircle(at: location)
            })
        ForEach(self.viewModel.currentArrangement.circles, id: \.id) { circle in
            return DraggableCircleView(viewModel: self.viewModel,
                       circleIndex: circle.circleIndex,
                       diameter: 50,
                       offset: circle.position)
        }
    }
}
```

}

**Relevant parts of the DraggableCircle View**

```
struct DraggableCircleView: View {
    init(viewModel: ViewModel, circleIndex: Int, diameter: CGFloat, offset: CGPoint) {
        // Initialize
        ...
        _viewState = /*State<CGSize>*/.init(initialValue: CGSize(width: offset.x, height: offset.y))

        // **Debugging print statement**
        print("\(self.viewModel.currentCircles.forEach{ print("Frame: \(self.viewModel.currentIndex), position \($0.position)") }) \n")
    }

    var body: some View {
    let minimumLongPressDuration = 0.0
    let longPressDrag = LongPressGesture(minimumDuration: minimumLongPressDuration)
        .sequenced(before: DragGesture())
        .updating($dragState) { value, state, transaction in
            // Update circle position during drag
            ...
        }
        .onEnded { value in
            guard case .second(true, let drag?) = value else { return }
            // get updated position of circle after drag
            ...
            self.viewModel.setPositionOfCircle(at: self.circleIndex, to: circlePosition)
        }
    
    return Circle()
        // Styling omitted
        ...
        .position(
            x: viewState.width + dragState.translation.width,
            y: viewState.height + dragState.translation.height
        )
        .gesture(longPressDrag)

}
```

Comment: TL, DR... [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Asperi Thanks for your comment. I've just updated the question. Do let me know if it can still be improved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. The issue lies with the .position(...) modifier of the `DraggableCircle` View. Previously, it was only reflecting the **state** of the DraggableCircle but was not updating based on the underlying ViewModel and Model.

Changing it to:

```
.position(
    x: self.viewModel.currentCircles[circleIndex].position.x + dragState.translation.width,
    y: self.viewModel.currentCircles[circleIndex].position.y + dragState.translation.height)
```

did the trick. This is because the position of the DraggableCircle now reflects the underlying ViewModel instead of just the state of the DraggableCircle.